# Find backup on Google Cloud VM SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, restore, database-backups

I have looked everywhere but need your input. I am Running SQL Server on a VM in GCP. The database is backed up and running full recovery mode.

Trying to restore within SSMS giving error:

> Cannot open backup device '{2E8E01BE-0C7B-4132-95C5-A881BE0C3B57}7'.

I guess backup is made on wherever google has space.

So, how can I find and restore from my backup?

Comment: Do the steps in one of these links [1][2] help you restore from your backup?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cloning-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-on-compute-engine#restore_the_sample_database 
[2]https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/backup-recovery/backups#where_backups_are_stored

Comment: Link 1 refers to having a *.bak file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS the backups shown refers to my auto disk snapshots. I had to

1. Create a new disk - recover from my snapshot.
2. Add It to my VM in console
3. Add it in windows VM (disk management) to D:
4. Make it writeable (using diskpart, list volume, select volume, attr disk clear readonly, attr volume clear readonly, attr volume clear hidden, attr volume clear shadowcopy.
5. Copy my SQL datafiles to VM Sql Data folder & attach database again.

Learning: Use Task scheduler to create *.bak files daily of all dbs and export to backup filestorage for easy recovery.